# Java game engine for android and desktop

Tags: java, 2d, android

I want implement 2d game as desktop application. And after development move it to android platform.

Engine should be have input and network managers.

Help me choose.

Comment: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend going with [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). It is great, I am currently using it a lot. You can build your game in 2D or 3D. It allows you to easily test your game on the desktop and if you want to move it to your Android device then all you have to add is about 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/), it currently gives Android and iOS basic versions for free until April 8th.

Comment: Unity3d based on C#. I want use Java. And set 'java' tag :)